# android exception for validating file exist not working

Tags: android, exception, filenotfoundexception

I've been working with Eclipse ADT for about 2 months. In that time, I have a small utility that allows me to select an IP Address and Port, and then send a file to that combo. The utility works as intended, but when I type in the wrong file name, the application hangs.

```
@Override
   public void run() {
      if (data != null) {
         this.send(data);
      } else if (this.file != null) {
         if (file.exists()) {
            this.send(file);
         } else {
            transferError = new FileNotFoundException("The specified file could not be found");
         }
      }
   }
```

**I've even tried to do the following in hopes that one or the other would throw, but I am unsuccessful in both.**

```
public void run() {
      if (data != null) {
         this.send(data);
      } else if (this.file != null) {
         if (file.exists()) {
            this.send(file);
         } else {
            transferError = new FileNotFoundException("The specified file could not be found");
         }
      }try {
         throw new Exception("blah blah blah");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

I've jockeyed around the exception, I've added the one above, I've tried placing it in different places, and all unsuccessful. Again, I'm exceptionally new to this, and got here from basically mincing various tcp client codes. Aside of creating a way to throw the exception correctly, please help me understand why the first one isn't working and why the one you suggest is.

Answer (score 0):

in your else block you aren't throwin the transferError you create.

```
throw transferError;
```

However you probably won't be able to do that because FileNotFoundException is a checked exception and the run() method doesn't declare any thrown exceptions.  You probably need to find a different way to present the error to the user, like with a Toast or something.

Your second block doesn't work because you are catching the exception you throw.

Comment: My toast results:
<pre>@Override
   public void run() {      
try {
run();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {Toast.makeText(FileSender.this, "The specified File could not be found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
</pre>
and I get the following error message:
<pre>
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (FileSender, String, int)
</pre>
likely can't toast here. Someone else suggested I may need to use a log message. I may be stuck for a little while, as I'm mincing code when I should be learning these classes and blocks.

Comment: Is FileSender an activity?  If not you'll need to have a context in order to toast.  Logging would be acceptable too, if you don't care that the user knows about the problem.

Comment: yes, it's an activity. But again, just learning this stuff is making it hard to understand how to fix it for unseen breaking. That said, I don't mind logging since I'm the user and don't care if someone knows about the problem. Do you have a suggestion you can provide in code that would help?